# Is there a search filter for all questions containing a string AND have an answer posted by me?

Tags: discussion, search

I'd like to run a search for questions containing a string (let's say `foo` for argument's sake) which have an answer that I've posted. I know I can run two separate queries for each half of this – `"foo" is:question answers:1..` and `is:answer user:me`, but is there some way to combine these?

Answer (score 5):

Looking at [the search help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching), there doesn't seem to be a way to search a *question* that relates to specified *answers* like that.

You'll have to use either [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) or [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Here's one way in SEDE:

```sql
SELECT     q.Id AS [Post Link],
           q.Score,
           q.Tags,
           q.Creationdate
FROM       Posts a
INNER JOIN Posts q
ON         q.Id = a.ParentId
WHERE      a.PostTypeId = 2 -- answer
AND        a.OwnerUserId = ##UserId:int##
AND        LOWER(q.Body) LIKE N'%' + LOWER(##SearchStr:string##) + '%'
```

Which you can [**See/Run live**](https://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/1025874/questions-containing-string-that-ive-answered?SearchStr=Pagan&UserId=9682).

---

SEDE is only updated once per week.  For fresher data, use the API -- but that's a fair bit more involved to code for something like this.

Answer (score 3):

[SEDE can do it](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1025875/questions-with-a-given-string-that-a-given-user-answered). (I don't know why, but I couldn't find any existing queries that seemed apropos. Maybe no one bothered naming their throwaway queries; this *is* admittedly pretty simple SQL.)

```sql
select q.id as [Post Link],q.score as [Question Score],q.ViewCount,q.Tags,a.score as [Answer Score]
from posts q inner join posts a on a.parentid = q.id
where a.owneruserid = ##UserID:int##
and (q.body like '%' + ##SearchString:string## + '%'
 or q.title like '%' + ##SearchString:string## + '%')
```